# Cannot call docker command inside container (docker.sock binding problem)

Tags: docker

So, I have CentOS 7 host (Digital Ocean) with installed docker. In one of containers I need to use Docker so I find solution with binding docker.sock:

```
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

but it doesn't work.

Then I checked host to see where docker.sock is located and path is:

```
/run/docker.sock
```

so I tried:

```
-v /run/docker.sock:/run/docker.sock
```

and

```
-v /run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

neither doesn't work.

Do anybody have an idea?

Thanks

EDIT: Fixed, the problem was user permissions.

Comment: What does `doesn't work` mean?

Comment: Sorry,

I skipped to add it, when I for example run:
docker ps
I'm getting: 'Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.29/containers/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied'
same thing works on local machine.

I know that there is permission issue, but I don't know how to deal with it.

Local machine is Ubuntu 18.04 and server is CentOS7(Digital Ocean).